# PyCharm run/debug configuration popup silence

Tags: python, pycharm, config

Is there a way to make a PyCharm Run/Debug configuration default, so it doesn't ask you which one you want to use everytime? I only have one for most projects.

I believe I've saved the default configuration by pressing "Save 'main' Configuration' in the drop down. It is no longer transparent. But it still doesn't seem to be the default.

When I open Defaults dropdown there is no way to copy/move a permanent config to the default. So I edit the default Python one by copy/pasting each field over and save.

But still I get the popup...

PyCharm Community 2017.2.2
Windows 10

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you read the [Docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html)?

Comment: Yes, but I guess I still don't understand. Edited question. Is there a way to easily go from: autocreated config -> permanent config -> default config? I have not been able to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my keymap. I was using the Visual Studio keymapping, and pressing F5 for debugging. But F5 is not mapped to Run->Debug by default, so the default run/debug configuration was never being invoked.

Totally my mistake for not verifying the keymapping. Though to be honest, for a Visual Studio keymapping, it is weird that F5 is not mapped to debug by default...